# Git-tf thowing permission denied over VPN

Tags: tfs, vpn, git-tf

I'm trying access our TFS server when VPN'd from home but it only gives me the following message:

```
Connecting to TFS...
git-tf: Permission denied: connect
```

I'm using a fully qualified URL and everything else works just fine over the VPN. Are there any authentication config settings I could try? I can't find mention of anything online anywhere.

And of course when I'm in the office it works just fine.

**EDIT - Stack trace from logs**

```
2012-10-12 10:07:31,231 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.httpclient.DefaultHTTPClientFactory) HttpClient configured for http://svrtfs2010.ms.innovativesol.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection, authenticating as innovative/jrusso
2012-10-12 10:07:31,535 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector) I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Permission denied: connect
2012-10-12 10:07:31,535 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector) Retrying request
2012-10-12 10:07:31,535 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector) I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Permission denied: connect
2012-10-12 10:07:31,535 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector) Retrying request
2012-10-12 10:07:31,535 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector) I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Permission denied: connect
2012-10-12 10:07:31,535 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector) Retrying request
2012-10-12 10:07:31,544 WARN  [main] (git-tf) Error executing command: pull --deep --rebase
com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:99)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.LocationExceptionMapper.map(LocationExceptionMapper.java:32)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.internal.LocationWebServiceProxy.connect(LocationWebServiceProxy.java:76)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.LocationService.connect(LocationService.java:754)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.LocationService.ensureConnected(LocationService.java:884)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.LocationService.ensureAuthenticated(LocationService.java:923)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConnection.ensureAuthenticated(TFSConnection.java:739)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getConnection(Command.java:354)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getConnection(Command.java:326)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getVersionControlClient(Command.java:474)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getVersionControlService(Command.java:492)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.PullCommand.run(PullCommand.java:140)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.Main.main(Main.java:319)
Caused by: com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.TransportException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:744)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:473)
    at ms.ws._LocationWebServiceSoap12Service.connect(_LocationWebServiceSoap12Service.java:384)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.framework.location.internal.LocationWebServiceProxy.connect(LocationWebServiceProxy.java:70)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:147)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:862)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1690)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:495)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:464)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:376)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:588)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: That's strange.  Do you have a full stack trace in your logs?  They're in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Logs`.

Comment: I hope that helps, I would love to continue using git-tf. I'm just learning Git but it has really improved my workflow over what it is with TFS.

Comment: Let me guess - JDK7 and Cisco VPN?

Comment: Yup :o/ I don't like the sounds of that

Comment: I had similar problem when using Spring STS, JDK 1.7 connecting to TFS over Cisco VPN. Using the option suggested in this thread (-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true), I was able to resolve my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to [Java bug 703177](http://www.java.net/node/703177).  Java 7 brings IPv6 support, and Cisco's VPN client reportedly rejects IPv6 traffic.  You can force Java to use IPv4 as its transit with the `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` system property.

You will need to edit the `git-tf` launcher scripts that start the JVM in order to do this.  You can add the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` argument to the launch line in both `git-tf` and `git-tf.cmd`.

The last lines of `git-tf` should be:

```
exec java -Xmx512m -classpath "$GITTF_CLASSPATH" \
    "-Dcom.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory=$BASE_DIRECTORY/native" \
    -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
    com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.Main "$@"
```

The 47th line of `git-tf.cmd` should be:

```
java -ea -Xmx512M -cp %GITTF_CLASSPATH% "-Dcom.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory=%BASE_DIRECTORY%native" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.Main %*
```

Comment: Glad to hear it - this one made me a bit nervous.  :)